# Finding a missing Dll on Windows Server Core in Docker

Tags: docker, windows-server-core

I am attempting to build a console application in a Windows Docker container using Windows Server Core, as per [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft.

The problem I am having is that, when run on the container, the application exits without an error message. I suspect that this is due to a missing system Dll on Windows Server Core, but unlike on Windows Desktop there is no application popup to identify the missing dll. Nor is there anything in the System log.

What else can I do to trouble shoot the issue?

Comment: Why do you suspect a missing DLL?

Comment: The default behaviour of the application is to print a help message. If I copy the application from the container and run it on the host, it runs correctly. If I then remove a dependent DLL and run it (again on the host), the application exits without a message - but I get the 'System Error' dialog popup.

Comment: So you already determined the DLL? Why don't you compile it into your application? Or add it to you app-package or something?

Comment: @Lenniey I don't know which DLL is missing. I only know that removing *a* DLL results in the same behaviour as I am seeing in Windows Server Core. I am looking for a way to find which DLL is missing, similar to the System Error popup that is shown in Windows Desktop.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Can't help you there, but maybe [this list from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee391643(v%3Dvs.85)) provides a starting point to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me (see more detailed explanation here https://stefanscherer.github.io/find-dependencies-in-windows-containers/):

1. Azure VM Windows server Core
2. Install Procmon and filter your process via iwr download.
3. Put your zip in to Azure BLOB and downlaod via SAS url and tar expand if archieve
4. Start your process.
5. Search fail/error entries.
6. Prey your missing DLL is not UI dll. Because VM Windows Core has UI, while docker version seems like not.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is searching for a way how to find out which dll was not found/resolved in the container which has no GUI, after few hours I found a tool called [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) that was the only one that really helped me. Micorsoft's [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-170) resolved only first layer of the tree and ldd from cygwin wasn't able to resolve names of some DLLs.

```
Dependencies.exe -chain my_executable.exe
```

Dependencies can build a whole graph with all DLLs that are being loaded recursively and it resolves their path to the system. From that graph you can then easily identify what is missing by searching for NOT_FOUND string.

Example output:

```
├ exe_dat.exe (ROOT) : ..\Release\exe_dat.exe 
|  ├ adtfstreaming_290.dll (ApplicationDirectory) : ..\Release\adtfstreaming_290.dll 
|  |  ├ MSVCP100.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP100.dll 
|  |  |  ├ MSVCR100.dll (WindowsFolder) : C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll 
|  |  |  |  ├ KERNEL32.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  ├ api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll (ApiSetSchema) : C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  ├ ntdll.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  ├ KERNELBASE.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\Windows\system32\kernelbase.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  |  ├ ntdll.dll (WellKnownDlls) : C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  |  ├ api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll (ApiSetSchema) : C:\Windows\system32\kernelbase.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  |  ├ api-ms-win-core-apiquery-l1-1-0.dll (ApiSetSchema) : C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  |  ├ api-ms-win-core-apiquery-l1-1-1.dll (ApiSetSchema) : C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll 
|  |  |  |  |  |  ├ ext-ms-win-advapi32-registry-l1-1-0.dll (ApiSetSchema) : C:\Windows\system32\advapi32.dll 
...
```